# Access denied (403) while writing data to S3 table using Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I created a external table pointing to S3 on EMR cluster using Hive. Now I am trying to insert data into the table using Spark, which is failing due to a permission issue but the same insert query is working using Hive shell.
Do I need to set access_key and secret_key in Spark? I did tried them in spark-shell but had no luck.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key","xxxxxxxxxx");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","xxxxxxxxxx");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.access.key","xxxxxxxxxx");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.secret.key","xxxxxxxxxx");
```

Am I missing something here?

```
create external table test
(
column1 string
) stored as parquet location 's3://bucket/data/test';
insert overwrite test select * from source;
```

Spark code:

```
spark.sql("insert overwrite table test select column1 from source_table")
```

Error:

> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
>   Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   AccessDenied; Request ID: 685BCC1B6F49A705) at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
>   at ...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without setting the access and secret keys for the Hadoop config?

Comment: it worked without setting access keys and secret keys

Comment: If the code is running in EMR under the same IAM account that owns the buckets, you shouldn't need to set those